# sqlite Prepare-error #26

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to read data from `sql` database in `obj c`. I have a problem because all time I receive

```
Prepare-error #26: file is encrypted or is not a database.
```

I tried everything what I found on the internet (I am looking for solutions lots of hours).

***My code:***

```
sqlite3 *database;
products = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString* sqlStatement = @"select * from products";
    const char *sql = [sqlStatement UTF8String];
    static sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
    if(result != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Prepare-error #%i: %s", result, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            int aId = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 1);
            NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
            NSString *aDescriptions = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
            double aDo = sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 4);

            Product *product = [[Product alloc]initWithUniqueId:aId name:aName descriptions:aDescriptions do:aDo];
            [products addObject:product];
            NSLog(@"%@",products);
        }
    } 
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: did you push the database from assets or did u create it with DatabaseHelper?

Answer (score 0):

I have almost identical code, and I see nothing wrong with your code. Error 26 is (according to sqlite3.h) "File opened that is not a database file".

I tried my code with a path to a text file, and got result=1 from sqlite3_prepare_v2() -- so sqlite3_open() passed without failure. I suspect your file is not an sqLite file, or perhaps is corrupt.

Try to verify the database file integrity by opening it with an sqLite editor application. Also logging the path to verify it wouldn't hurt. If there are spaces in the path they might need to be escaped -- or not, I can't recall.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It looks I have bad database, but how can i create good sqlite db?

Comment: Use sqlite3_open_v2() with the flag SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE. The file must not already exist at this location for a new database to be created. See http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html.